# What is the sum of the products of digits of all three digit numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I proceed? All approaches are welcomed.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Can you do the same thing with one digit numbers? Two digit numbers?

Comment: I tried solving  by taking 101-200 , 200-300 .. etc ranges and applied permutations and I got struck.

Comment: Really, the case of two digit numbers shows you the pattern.

Comment: @lulu Is there anything better than brute force ?

Comment: It is usually advisable to post your own work along with the question. Please share your work.

Comment: It doesn't require any force at all.  You can do it in your head. And I think that you'll see the relevant pattern if you work out the easier cases.

Comment: Okay good then. Let me try with 2 digit numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can break the numbers in brackets of  $100$. For numbers from $101-199$, the product of two digits will be multiplied by $1$. Similarly, for $201-299$, they will be multiplied by $2$. So on and so forth. Note that the sum of product of two digits is the same in every case; call it $P_2$. Hence, we need to evaluate $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n} k\cdot P_2 = 45 P_2$. Now we can apply the same technique on $P_2$ by breaking it in brackets of $10$. Consider numbers from $11-19, 21-29$, so on and so forth. For $11-19$, the sum of product has $1$ common in all the terms. Similarly, for $21-29$, $2$ is common in all the terms. If we take the common term out, the sum of the product of digits is the common term multiplied by $45$. Hence, $P_2 = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{9} k \cdot 45 = 2025$. Hence, the answer is $45^3 = 91125$.